# Angular JS: How to show if a date is today or yesterday using filters

Tags: angularjs

I have JSON in which they have provided transaction details with date(transaction date) in millisecond. Please refer JSON as below:

```
[
  {
"id": "contentAttributes/title",
"date": 1490169040579,
"price": "2,99",
"transactionStatus": "COMPLETED",
"contentName": "GooglePlay Movies, Big Bang Theory",
"merchantName": "abc",
"emailId": "abc",
"opco": "en_GB"
},


{
"id": "contentAttributes/title",
"date": 1490169040580,
"price": "4,99",
"transactionStatus": "PENDING",
"contentName": "GoolePlay Store, Snapseed",
"emailId": "abc",
"opco": "en_GB"
},
]
```

I have to show the transaction date to user as like below:

If transaction has completed Today

```
   Transaction Name: ABC purchased

   Transaction Date: Today, 11:15AM
```

If transaction has completed Yesterday

```
   Transaction Name: ABC purchased

   Transaction Date: Yesterday, 03:15PM
```

If transaction has completed Day before Yesterday

```
   Transaction Name: ABC purchased

   Transaction Date: Name of day[Sunday], 11:15AM
```

Which filter should I use to display the date in above format? I tried to use Angular filter but I am not getting required format.

I think I have to write Custom filter for this. Could you please help on this?

Comment: I used "<p class="tranDate">{{transaction.date | date:'EEEE, H:mma'}}</p>" but it shows as Sunday, 02:30PM . This solved my third part but still stuck with first and second.

Comment: try moment.js https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Comment: *I think I have to write Custom filter for this*: yes, that's correct. Try doing so, and come back if you have a concrete problem.

Comment: @JBNizet, As I am new with Angular JS not much familier with custom filter so could you please help me on this?

Comment: Sure: here's the documentation for filters. It explains how to create custom filters: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter. But really, you should be able to find and read the documentation by yourself.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom filter and reuse the date filter. A filter is just a function that takes an input and gives an output:

The one you are looking for is:

- One that takes the date
- If the date is "today's date", return "Today H:mma"
- If the date is "yesterday's date", return "Yesterday H:mma"
- Else return "EEEE H:mma"

You could use Date's methods such as getFullYear, getMonth and getDate in order to compare in which of the cases an especific date is.

Here is a rough example

```
app.filter('formatdate', function($filter) {
  return function(timestamp) {
    var currentDate = new Date()
    var toFormat = new Date(timestamp)
    if(toFormat.getDate() == currentDate.getDate() && toFormat.getMonth() == currentDate.getMonth() && toFormat.getFullYear() == currentDate.getFullYear() ) {
      return 'Today ' + $filter('date')(toFormat.getTime(), 'H:mma')
    }
    if(toFormat.getDate() == (currentDate.getDate() - 1) && toFormat.getMonth() == currentDate.getMonth() && toFormat.getFullYear() == currentDate.getFullYear()) {
      return 'Yesterday ' + $filter('date')(toFormat.getTime(), 'H:mma')
    }

      return $filter('date')(toFormat.getTime(), 'EEEE H:mma')
  }
})
```

You can use it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="purchase in data">
  {{purchase.date | formatdate}}
</div>
```

Here is a working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qvbogd?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks for your help! Using above code also I am getting "Monday, 18:02" not "Today , 18:02".

Comment: @SopanShinde I updated the code, the filter was returning the current date instead of the date that is being filtering. On the other hand, the dates in the data you are referencing to are on March 2017 (in case they are UNIX timestamps)

Comment: Thanks for your help on this! My problem has been resolved.